# помогите решить задачку. Условие ниже

Tags: python

Вам дано предложение: s = "There is some numbers: 49 and 432. How, to? split. text! I 123 can 45 play 67 football.". С помощью библиотеки re вам нужно из исходного предложения удалить всё кроме слов, точки, восклицательного знака и знака вопроса. Слова и наши знаки окончания предложения должны быть разделены пробелом. Символы приведены к нижнему регистру. Используйте метод sub или findall.
вот тут моя попытка сделать это самостоятельно:

```
import re
s=input()
s=s.lower()
re = re.sub("[49325671,:]", '', s)
res = ''.join(map(lambda ch: ch+' ', re))
print(res)
```

Comment: Предоставьте ваш вариант решения и опишите, что не получается или где сомнения в правильности

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, что, ж, следуя вашей логике:

```py
import re
s = "There is some numbers: 49 and 432. How, to? split. text! I 123 can 45 play 67 football."
s = s.lower()
pattern = r":?\s\d{1,}|,"
# буквально значит "двоеточие (ноль или больше раз), пробельный символ, любая цифра (один или более раз) ИЛИ запятая
t = re.sub(pattern, "", s)
```

и как результат имеем:

```py
>>> t
'there is some numbers and. how to? split. text! i can play football.'
```

Comment: Вы все правильно сделали, но ответ все равно не принимается почему-то, похоже создатели сайта с этим вопросом сами не знают чего хотят

Comment: Понял в чем ошибка, перед знаками препинания нет пробелов, как это должно быть по заданию

Comment: ПЕРЕД знаками препинания должны быть пробелы? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, почему-то даже когда между кавычками поставил пробел, то пробел ставится только после первой точки

Answer (score 0):

```
 import re
s = "There is some numbers: 49 and 432. How, to? split. text! I 123 can 45 play 67 football."
s = s.lower()
pattern = r":?\s\d{1,}|,"
# буквально значит "двоеточие (ноль или больше раз), пробельный символ, любая цифра (один или более раз) ИЛИ запятая
t = re.sub(pattern, " ", s) (вот тут был пропущен пробел)
print(t)
```

В общем спасибо всем большое
Человек, который прислал свой код просто забыл поставить пробел между кавычкам, теперь все работает

Comment: Да, я человек) и я не забывал, я следовал вашему условию, который вы описали. Создавать еще один такой же ответ не очень корректно, даже с пробелом